# Which adjective can I use here?

Tags: adjectives

The bouncer pulled the two men apart. One of the men had a black eye, while the other had a bloody nose.

I assume that the eye wouldn't be black yet right after the fight, so my question is which adjective would be the most common to use here instead? Battered? Bruised?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that the eye wouldn't be black yet right after the fight, ...

Yes, that is right. But the area around the eye can very well be **bruised** (reddish in colour) and/or **swollen**.